# What is the ideal size of cluster to manage S3 file of 24 GB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm currently working with this dataset
s3://commoncrawl/crawl-001/2008/06/19/1/. It size is 24GB and i'm trying to separing it in just text/html requests and save it in my S3 bucket. Everything is ok with the code, but when i'm trying to save it in my bucket, I had problems with my memory:

`Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  11.1 GB of 11 GB physical memory used.`

Initially, I started with a master node with two slaves m5.xlarge, later I tried to put the master and the slaves with m5.2xlarge and it isn't enough.

Do you have any idea of what could be a correct size for the cluster to process this file?

I'm using kernel pyspark and reading this file as an rdd and I have to save it as a csv file in my bucket:

```py
rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles('s3://commoncrawl/crawl-001/2008/06/19/1/')
```

And after to process it, I save it in finalRdd:

```py
def toCSVLine(data):
  return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)

results = finalRdd.map(toCSVLine)
results.saveAsTextFile(
    path="s3://mybucket/folder/results/pages.csv",
    compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec"
)
```

Edit 1: the problem with the increasing the cluster's size is that this shows afther than one hour of execution: "Session isn't active".

Comment: don't write to a single big file, but write one chunk per partition.
Not sure how it's done in Python pysparks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently using `wholeTextFiles()` method to read file from S3. As stated in [Spark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles.html), it means load all content of file in memory. So, to read a 24GB file, you will need more than 24GB of memory on your instance.

As your udf method is called `toCSVLine`, I guess you don't want to read your file as a whole but line per line. To do so, you can use `textFile()` method instead of `wholeTextFile()`. By doing so, Spark will read file line per line and so avoid Memory limit error.

More details about reading text file with Spark here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-text-file-rdd-dataframe/

Comment: Actually, I need to read it all as I need to separate what is html and the only way I could achieve it is by reading the whole file.

To get this, i used regex to match the html requests and I separated them in tuples.  

It means that every tuple that I have in my last rdd reference are tuples with the info that I need.

Comment: You'll need something big to process each file, *but limit the #of threads per worker to keep memory down*. Then save in something other than CSV as its an awful format for subsequent queries